# Issue installing nuget package to umbraco project in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget, umbraco, .net-4.5

I have a freshly set up Umbraco 7.13.2 project in VSCode (not visual studio) using the following method:
https://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/implementor/fundamentals/installation/spin-umbraco-cms-up-using-vs-code/

I am now trying to install the nuget package UmbracoCms.RestApi v0.9

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot find any .csproj or .fsproj file for your project! Please fix this error and try again.

My question:

**Is there a way to install these nuget packages that require a .csproj file in VSCode or will I have to use Visual Studio?**

Comment: There may be but I have a frontend developer next to me at work that's using VS Code and we couldn't get it to work. We did try a lot.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't get it to work in the end either so I just resorted to Visual Studio.